# Accessing a state with dynamic key name in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0, react-state

I have a state in React something like this:

```
type MyState = {
  xCount: number;
  yCount: number;
};
```

I want to access a state without knowing it's name while coding the program.

```
export class BodyWidget extends React.Component<BodyWidgetProps> {
  state: MyState = {
    xCount: 1,
    yCount: 1
  };

returnState = (name:any) {
  return this.state[name]
}

...
}
```

When I am trying this i get this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'MyState'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
returnState = (name: keyof MyState) {
  return this.state[name]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The error says that 'name' should be one of MyState properties(xCount or yCount), like this:

```
returnState = (name: keyof MyState) => {
    return this.state[name];
}
```